# Maven must compile before install (package) in mutil module maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a Spring boot maven project (mutil-module) like this:

```
-parent
|
|-child1
| |-src
| |-pom.xml
|
|-child2
| |-src
| |-pom.xml
|
|-pom.xml
```

Problem:

- I always must be run `mvn compile` before can run `mvn package` or `mvn install`.
- If I run `mvn clean install` then build will failed
- I guess: Something happen when `install(package)` ignore `compile` in lifecycle.
  -- Trace error if `package` without `compile` first

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat
.ccw.common.constant does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for ccw-platform 1.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] ccw-platform ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.479 s]
[INFO] ccw-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  2.070 s]
[INFO] ccw-config-service ................................. SUCCESS [  0.585 s]
[INFO] ccw-game-service-contract .......................... FAILURE [  0.666 s]
[INFO] ccw-game-service ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service-contract ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-27T19:21:18+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ccw-game-service-contract: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat
.ccw.common.constant does not exist
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ccw-game-service-contract: Compilation failure
/F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat.ccw.com
mon.constant does not exist
```

-- Full details

```
F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common:${ccw-common.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\pom.xml, line
14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-config-service:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-config-service:${ccw-config-service.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-confi
g-service\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-game-service-contract:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-game-service-contract:${ccw-game-service-contract.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-W
orld\ccw-game-service-contract\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service:${ccw-user-management-service.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Che
ss-World\ccw-user-management-service\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service-contract:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service-contract:${ccw-user-management-service-contract.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess
-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-user-management-service-contract\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] ccw-platform                                                       [pom]
[INFO] ccw-common                                                         [jar]
[INFO] ccw-config-service                                                 [jar]
[INFO] ccw-game-service-contract                                          [jar]
[INFO] ccw-game-service                                                   [jar]
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service-contract                               [jar]
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service                                        [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-platform >--------------------
[INFO] Building ccw-platform 1.0                                          [1/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ ccw-platform ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ccw-platform ---
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\pom.xml to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-platform\1.0\ccw-platform-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common >---------------------
[INFO] Building ccw-common 1.0                                            [2/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\target\classes
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World>mvn -e install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common:${ccw-common.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\pom.xml, line
14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-config-service:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-config-service:${ccw-config-service.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-confi
g-service\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-game-service-contract:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-game-service-contract:${ccw-game-service-contract.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-W
orld\ccw-game-service-contract\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service:${ccw-user-management-service.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Che
ss-World\ccw-user-management-service\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service-contract:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-user-management-service-contract:${ccw-user-management-service-contract.version}, F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess
-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-user-management-service-contract\pom.xml, line 14, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] ccw-platform                                                       [pom]
[INFO] ccw-common                                                         [jar]
[INFO] ccw-config-service                                                 [jar]
[INFO] ccw-game-service-contract                                          [jar]
[INFO] ccw-game-service                                                   [jar]
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service-contract                               [jar]
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service                                        [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-platform >--------------------
[INFO] Building ccw-platform 1.0                                          [1/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ ccw-platform ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ccw-platform ---
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\pom.xml to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-platform\1.0\ccw-platform-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-common >---------------------
[INFO] Building ccw-common 1.0                                            [2/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Building jar: F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\target\ccw-common-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ccw-common ---
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\target\ccw-common-1.0.jar to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-common\1.0\ccw-common-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-common\pom.xml to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-common\1.0\ccw-common-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-config-service >-----------------
[INFO] Building ccw-config-service 1.0                                    [3/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-config-service\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-config-service\target\ccw-config-service-1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ ccw-config-service ---
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-config-service\target\ccw-config-service-1.0.jar to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-config-service\1.0\ccw
-config-service-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-config-service\pom.xml to C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\doubleat\ccw\ccw-config-service\1.0\ccw-config-service-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------< com.doubleat.ccw:ccw-game-service-contract >-------------
[INFO] Building ccw-game-service-contract 1.0                             [4/7]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ ccw-game-service-contract ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ccw-game-service-contract ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to F:\Workspace\Chinese-Chess-World\Public-Repo\Chinese-Chess-World\Chinese-Chess-World\ccw-game-service-contract\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat
.ccw.common.constant does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for ccw-platform 1.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] ccw-platform ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.479 s]
[INFO] ccw-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  2.070 s]
[INFO] ccw-config-service ................................. SUCCESS [  0.585 s]
[INFO] ccw-game-service-contract .......................... FAILURE [  0.666 s]
[INFO] ccw-game-service ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service-contract ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] ccw-user-management-service ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-27T19:21:18+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ccw-game-service-contract: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat
.ccw.common.constant does not exist
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ccw-game-service-contract: Compilation failure
/F:/Workspace/Chinese-Chess-World/Public-Repo/Chinese-Chess-World/Chinese-Chess-World/ccw-game-service-contract/src/main/java/com/doubleat/ccw/usermanagement/CcwGameServiceContractApplication.java:[3,40] package com.doubleat.ccw.com
mon.constant does not exist
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to `<module>someChild</module>` ?? ;)

Comment: and 3 (completely) different(&independant) things: -directory structure, -pom inheritance, -multi-module (by convention we (me at least) consider it all the same, but you *can do* crazy things with these 3.)

Comment: Please post the complete output from the Maven. Do you happen to run spring-boot-maven-plugin for the modules before ccw-game-service-contract?

Comment: As you wrote `I always must be run mvn compile before can run mvn package or mvn install.` that is an indicator that your build structure/dependencies are simply wrong... Is that project available on Github etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise. It here https://github.com/Puskin2911/Chinese-Chess-World

Comment: @xerx593 I had already have <module></module>

Comment: @IllyaKysil . I think is yes, i updated full details in the question

Comment: The github version (branch v1.0/dev, commit cebd597) has problems you need to resolve first, to get a clear and deterministic build. Don't set the version of your artifacts with a property - it's not supported by maven (instead use mvn versions:set to manage them). And most importantly: ccw-common includes the spring-boot-maven plugin: this will create an executable jar, which you can't use as a library in your other modules because the classes are not where the class-loader expects to find them (there in BOOT-INF/classes, iso at the root-level of the jar).

Comment: How can i use ccw-common as a library, remove spring-boot-maven plugin or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Diagnostics**

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` executes for each of the modules in the project as evidenced by the following lines in Maven output:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:repackage (repackage) @ ccw-game-service-contract ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
```

The JAR artifact of such modules is not a usual library after that, but an executable JAR packaged as described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#repackage)

That executable JAR is not suitable for consumption by a Java compiler - or compiler for any other JVM-based language for that matter.

---

**Solution**

Only the Maven module which represents the final executable artifact of the project should include the invocation of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

You may check the official guide from Spring Boot - [Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) - for a step-by-step guide and explanation.

Comment: One more thing! I design a micro-service base on spring cloud and spring boot. service communication together by contract-service. This is good design, right? Or any solution, pattern for this, can you show me ? Thank youy

Comment: I am sorry, but it is impossible to give MEANINGFUL answer to this question in 600 characters, having no understanding and/or knowledge of your business context, and goals.